# Blazor .NET 8 Production deploy yields System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

Recently I have upgraded my .NET 6 Blazor server-side web application to .NET 8. Now I have an issue with deployment and get a `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException` in the Event viewer.

Is it looking for the `wwwroot` on my development machine?

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException:
> D:\Documents\Visual_Studio_Projects\Blazor\BlazorXXXX\wwwroot\

I tried many things after reading many Microsoft pages re Blazor deploy, but can't seem to find anything relating to this issue.

In my `Program.cs` I have :

```
builder.Host.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
```

Commenting this out or not makes no difference.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

**Edit**:
Resolved. I tried the install on a different server, and it worked.  Then I created a brand-new folder, and it works.  Probably remaining artefacts in the original deploy folder that interfered somehow.